# no single-String constructor/factory method

Tags: python, json, jackson

I'm currently using CURL to PUT an http request to a URL in a shell script with the following:

```
RES=`curl $USER -X PUT -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -d "{\"type\":\"$TYPE\",\"data\":[${STORES}]}" ${STR}`
```

This works just fine.  However, I'm trying to rewrite this in Python, but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
url = 'https://url.com/polling/v1/5cb401c5-bded-40f8-84bb-6566cdeb3dbb/stores'
data = urllib.urlencode({"type":"store","data":"9953"})
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % creds)
request.add_header("Content-type", "application/json")
request.add_header("Accept", "application/json")
print "Data: %s" % request.get_data()
print "Accept: %s" % request.get_header("Accept")
print "Content-Type: %s" % request.get_header("Content-type")
print "Authorization: %s" % request.get_header("Authorization")
try:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data )
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print e.read()
    exit()
data = json.loads(result.read())
print data
```

The exception I'm getting is "JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.sherwin.polling.push.nouns.util.StoreForm] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method"

I'm assuming that this means that the server (I don't have access to this code) is getting the data as a single string, but the constructor is expecting two strings?  If so, how would I construct this to be two strings?  If not, what might I be doing wrong?

EDIT: The server admin told me I need to format my data like
{"type":"store","data":["9953"]}
So I changed to:

```
data = urllib.urlencode({"type":"store","data":["9953"]})
```

but it doesn't work either, 
I'm seeing the data output here as
Data: data=%5B%279953%27%5D&type=store

Edit: I stripped out the encoding and am sending it as a string:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data='{"type":"store","data":["9953"]}')
```

So now my data output matches what its supposed to look like
Data: {"type":"store","data":["9953"]}

But now I'm getting:
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for ARRAY (from [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@614ba804; line: 2, column: 15])

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib to simplify your code, for example:

```
import requests

requests.put('url.com', data={"type":"store","data":"9953"}).json()
```

Or you can try to use json.dumps() function and use urllib2.urlopen:

```
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
urllib2.urlopen(request, json.dumps({"type":"store","data":"9953"}))
```